# Prototype keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What is `prototype` property, and why is it necessary? So far, I have learnt that this provides public access to more intrinsic, and private `prototype` of the object; is that correct?

Also, what's the difference between following statements?

```
MyConstructor.age = 30;
MyConstructor.prototype.age = 30;
```

In short, I need a better understanding of keyword `prototype`.

Thanks

Comment: You need to take your time to learn more about JavaScript. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work

Comment: this has been bothering me...i love this question

Comment: So can anybody explain why you there are two ways to create new properties i.e."You can add new properties to an existing object by simply giving it a value" person.age=30; and person.prototype.age = 30; does the same thing what is the difference

Comment: ok i got it: (let me know right or wrong) with person.age you need the object to be created already...and with person.prototype.age this will be added in the class and every object that uses that class.

Comment: Sime: he is trying to learn more about JS, that's why he (and I) are here. Not everyone learns well from videos (I certainly don't!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the purpose of prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/what-s-the-purpose-of-prototype)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

"Prototype" is something that plays a role in objects.

In Javascript, everything is an object. Every object has a kind, and thus inherits the `prototype` of that kind.

For example, take a simple array: `var a = []`. You can make operations with it, like `a.push(10)`. Where does this `push` method come from? From the prototype of `Array` object, which `a` is.

You can add your own methods to `Array` objects just by defining them in the `prototype` object. For example:

```
Array.prototype.sortNum = function() {this.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b});};
```

This way you can do something like `a.sortNum()` with *all* arrays, even the ones created before you defined the `sortNum` method.

(Note: for compatibility reasons, it's usually not recommended to extend the prototype of native objects like `Array`s. But this particular example is usually a welcome addition, as well as normalizing methods like `map` and `forEach` for older browsers.)

(Just **never ever** extend `Object.prototype`! Unless you don't care to mess up `for...in` statements, the `in` operator and these sort of cases.)

If you want to define your own classes, like the name `MyConstructor` suggests, you'll have to define its `prototype` to define the methods for all the instances of that class:

```
function MyConstructor(name) {this.name = name};
MyConstructor.prototype = {
    print: function() {return this.name;}
};

var mc = new MyConstructor("foo");
alert(mc.print()); // alerts "foo"
```

You can define more than just functions in `prototype`s, too:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.age = 30;

alert(mc.age); // alerts 30
```

Watch out when you do this to define "default" object values, because changing it may cause a change in *all* instances of that class.

But this comes handy with `Object.defineProperty`:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyConstructor.prototype, "wholeString", {
    get: function() {return this.name + "=" + this.age;},
    set: function(v) {this.name = v.substring(3);}
});

alert(mc.wholeString); // alerts "foo = 30"
```

(Unfortunately, IE<9 allows this only for DOM objects...)

When you define `MyConstructor.age = 30` instead, what you're actually doing is defining a member of the *function* `MyConstructor`, so `mc.age` would be undefined. Every instance of `MyConstructor` inherits the methods and members defined in `MyConstructor.prototype`, not the ones of the function `MyConstructor`.

There's much more to say, actually. Objects can be of a subclass of another class, thus inheriting the `prototype` of the superclass, too. For example, `document.body` is an instance of `HTMLBodyElement`, which is a subclass of `HTMLElement`, which is a subclass of `Element` and so on, until you get `Object` as the upmost superclass. So, `document.body` inherits all the methods defined in the prototype of `HTMLBodyElement`, `HTMLElement`, `Element` and `Object`. This is called the prototype chain.

Doing the same with custom objects is a bit tricky:

```
function Class() {};
Class.prototype.foo = function() {alert("foo");};

function Subclass() {};
Subclass.prototype = new Class();
Subclass.prototype.bar = function() {alert("bar");};

var a = new Class(), b = new Subclass();
a.foo(); // alerts"foo"
a.bar(); // throws an error
b.foo(); // alerts "foo"
b.bar(); // alerts "bar"

a instanceof Class;    // true
a instanceof Subclass; // false
b instanceof Class;    // true
b instanceof Subclass; // true
```

Comment: awesome explantion... could you guide me to an exhaustive tutorial on object oriented javascript - I would be eventually using it to generate the html5 controls (and extended ones) at run time for my work... the tuorials by Douglas Crockford are really not that that conceptive and the slides by E John also lack explanation... thanks...

Comment: @user503510 Gee, Crockford and Resig are two of the main Javascript gurus. Every Javascript programmer has learnt something from them. You can try the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US) about OOP programming or the one from [JavascriptKit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/oopjs.shtml).

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, function objects have a built-in `.prototype` property. The value of this property is an object. If the function is used as a constructor, the resulting instances inherit from that "prototype" object.

Example:

```
var Dog = function () {}; // the constructor function

Dog.prototype.bark = function () {}; // adding a method to Dog.prototype

var dog1 = new Dog; // creating a new instance

dog1.bark(); // the instance inherits the "bark" method from Dog.prototype
```

Note that the `.prototype` property (of function objects) is not the same as the `[[Prototype]]` internal property. All objects contain the latter. It's an internal reference to an object's prototype. (In the above example, the `dog1` object's `[[Prototype]]` refers to `Dog.prototype`.) On the other hand, only function objects have a built-in `.prototype` property (which makes sense since only function objects can be used as constructors).

Comment: This explains it pretty well too (thanks for this) but I would need to select the top most as the answer - it is much more elaborate and explains other things as well...

Comment: short and sweet :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var foo = function () {};
foo.bar = 5;
foo.prototype.foobar = 10;

var x = new foo();
x.bar; // undefined
x.foobar; // 10
```

Edit: Also, you can then do

```
foo.prototype.foobar = 20;
x.foobar; // 20
```