# Difference between using or not using prototype: they seem apparently to do the same

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between using or not using `prototype`? They apparently do the same.

With `prototype`:

```
function poligon(angles){
     this.angles = angles;
}
poligon.prototype.color = function(){ return "blue"; }

var mypol = new poligon(14);

alert(mypol.color());
```

Without `prototype`:

```
function poligon(angles){
     this.angles = angles;
}
poligon.color = function(){ return "blue"; }

var mypol = new poligon(12);

alert(poligon.color());
```

What does it really mean adding a "color" object with `prototype` and without it?

Comment: A previous post explains prototype pretty good http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064104/prototype-keyword-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is not always clear when introduced to javascript prototypes.

If you add a method to the prototype, every single object inheriting from that prototype will have this function from that point on. In this case, your class/function 'poligon' is probably the only class inheriting from this prototype.

The difference comes when you declare a new type, 'rectangle' for example, for which you declare `rectangle.prototype = poligon.prototype;`. Now your rectangle class will inherit all methods declared in the poligon **prototype**, which wouldn't be the case if you just added the method to 'poligon'.

Inheritance works differently in javascript, and is at times very confusing when coming from a classic OOP language.

Answer (score 1):

By using prototypes like you do there is no difference, but the prototype comes in handy when you're creating new objects derived from your `Poligon` object.

```
Poligon.print = function() {};
new Poligon().print(); // Has no method print

Poligon.prototype.print = function() {};
new Poligon().print(); // Tah dah!
```