# Why include .prototype in the function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am reading John Resig's slideshow http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#78
Its not clear to me why i need to include `.prototype` in the line `Me.prototype = new Person();`

```
function Person(){}
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
  return this.name;
};

function Me(){
  this.name = "John Resig";
}
Me.prototype = new Person();

var me = new Me();
assert( me.getName(), "A name was set." );
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way, if every person is going to have a name, it's easier to assign the `getName` function to it's prototype.

In this case, you have a **Person** that has a prototype function to get a name, and a few lines below you have a **Me** function that assigns a name by default.  Since we want to incorporate the `getName` function, we use the `Person` which already has that function object  built-in.  When you construct `Me()` and assign to `me` you can call `getName()` and use that to return the name, which by default is **"John Resig"**

The same thing can be achieved without prototype, like this

```
function Me(){
  this.name = "John Resig";
  this.getName = function () {
    return this.name;
  }
}

var me = new Me();
```

...BUT by using prototype, it helps create objects a lot faster, you can [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype) as well.