# When do javascript reference a function, that are used in constructors?

Tags: javascript

I usually extend constructor functions with the `.prototype` property, to have multiple instances reference the same code (instead of having several identical code), like this:

```
function Effect(){}
Effect.prototype.run = function(){}
```

However, due to the structure of my current project, I would like to do something like this:

Define `effects` object, with effect options:

```
var effects = {
    e1 : {
        run: function(){console.log(this);}
    },
    e2 : {
        run: function(){console.log(this);}
    }
}
```

Create Effect instance using the object definitions

```
function Effect(effect) {
    this.run = effect.run;    
}
```

Now I can create several instances (maybe hundreds)

```
var E1 = new Effect(effects.e1);
var E2 = new Effect(effects.e2);
var E3 = new Effect(effects.e2);
.....
```

However I'm concerned, if the `.run` functions will be defined multiple times.

Will these new instances reference the same function (defined in the `effects` object), or will they create a new 'local' function for each instance, using up memory space?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you could pass a reference `run: functionRun1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is an object, and as such it will always be stored by reference. Assigning it to a different variable or property will only create a new reference to the existing function object, and eat not more memory than needed for that variable or property.

Comment: But according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype , the function is created on each instance. Just wondering if that is the case in my example.

Comment: Because there, the *function expression is evaluated* on every constructor call, creating a new function object each time (and then assigning it to the respective instance). It's not the assignment that is responsible for this.

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense. Sometimes it's just about the right phrasing :)