# Correct way to create a plugin

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a plugin for JavaScript, and I want to add usable methods to it. (ex. `myPlugin.usefulMethod()`) The way I would do it is as follows:

```
function MyPlugin(param1, param2) {
    ...

    this.usefullMethod = function() {...};

    this.anotherUserfullMethod = function(someParam) {...};
}

var plugin1 = new MyPlugin(someParam1, someParam2);
plugin1.usefullMethod();
```

But I've see a lot of plugin create their methods like this:

```
function MyPlugin(param1, param2) {
    ...
}
MyPlugin.prototype.usefullMethod = function() {...};

MyPlugin.prototype.anotherUserfullMethod = function(someParam) {...};
```

Which is the correct way, and why? What's the difference between them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype

Comment: Better use the term 'module' instead of a 'plugin'.

Comment: reference link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: @BenG Thanks! So it's basically saying to use `MyPlugin.prototype` because it's faster. Correct?

Comment: A third option is to use an IIFE instead of the prototype. I personally prefer this one because prototypes give me headaches.

Comment: @4castle Thanks! I know what IIFE is, but I don't quite understand how it can be used instead of prototype.

Comment: @Horay Declare the functions in the IIFE, and then in the function that you return, assign `this.usefulMethod = usefulMethod;`

Comment: @janje Thanks! If I use prototype, then how can I use the local variables?

Comment: @Horay you use `this` when you NEED to access local variables.

Comment: @ahitt6345 Meaning, the variable I want to access in prototype, I do `this.myVar = 'something';`?

Comment: @Horay If you want to store a variable in the prototype, you need to do `MyPlugin.prototype.myVar = 'something';`