# A function is not working in javaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am learning javaScript and developing a todoList app. I have put everything in an object called todoList,then at very first there's an array of objects that stores tasks in todoList. Every object has two properties i.e (todo=text, status=boolean). After that is a function called `showTasks` to display tasks in todoList. There is an if statement in `showTasks` function to check if the todoList is empty or not. After that is a for loop to display all the tasks in the array. Another if statement comes after the for loop to display the status of the tasks. The `addTask` function is for adding new tasks in the list that adds only the text for the task without the status (status is false by default). The `editTask` and `deleteTask` functions are pretty self explanatory. The last function called toggleStatus is to switch the status of a task and it is not working and i can't figure out why.

```
var todoList = {

// Storing tasks
tasks: [],

// Displaying tasks
showTasks: function() {
    if (this.tasks.length === 0) {
        console.log("There's no tasks in the list.");
    } else {
        console.log("My Tasks:");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
            if (this.tasks.status === true) {
                console.log("(X)", this.tasks[i].todo);
            } else {
                console.log("( )", this.tasks[i].todo);
            }
        }
    }
},

// Adding a new task
addTask: function(task) {
    this.tasks.push({
        todo: task,
        status: false
    });
    this.showTasks();
},

// Editing an existing task
editTask: function(count,task) {
    this.tasks[count].todo = task;
    this.showTasks();
},

// Deleting a task
deleteTask: function(count) {
    this.tasks.splice(count,1);
    this.showTasks();
},
// Changing status
toggleStatus: function(count) {
  var task = this.tasks[count];
    task.status = !task.status;
    this.showTasks();
}

};
```

Comment: How are you calling `toggleStatus`? Are you getting errors in your Dev Tools console tab?

Comment: Can you please upload the html as well to check where the toggleStatus function is being called

Comment: i haven't created any html file till now. i am calling todoList.toggleStatus in console.log and when i do so it should display that specific task with a (X) as mentioned in showTasks function. but its appearing like "( )Task 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement in `for` loop have a typo :D

This is the good syntax:

```
if (this.tasks[i].status) {
```

By the way I would wrote it like that, prototyping is kind better because your object don't store as many functions as objects declared and then is faster to create ;) see [JS - Why use Prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype)

```js
function TodoList() {
    // Storing tasks
    this.tasks = [];
}


TodoList.prototype = {
    // Displaying tasks
    showTasks: function() {
        if (this.tasks.length === 0) {
            console.log("There's no tasks in the list.");
        } else {
            console.log("My Tasks:");
            for (var i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++) {
                if (this.tasks[i].status) {
                    console.log("(X)", this.tasks[i].todo);
                } else {
                    console.log("( )", this.tasks[i].todo);
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Adding a new task
    addTask: function(task) {
        this.tasks.push({
            todo: task,
            status: false
        });
        this.showTasks();
    },

    // Editing an existing task
    editTask: function(count, task) {
        this.tasks[count].todo = task;
        this.showTasks();
    },

    // Deleting a task
    deleteTask: function(count) {
        this.tasks.splice(count, 1);
        this.showTasks();
    },
  
    // Changing status
    toggleStatus: function(count) {
      var taskStatus = !this.tasks[count].status;
      this.tasks[count].status = taskStatus;
      this.showTasks();
    }
};

var t = new TodoList();
t.addTask("yowwww");
t.addTask("miaou");
t.editTask(1, "miawwwwwou");
t.toggleStatus(0)
```

Comment: i need the todoList in an object but you turned it into a function? is this the only way to make my code work?

Comment: Sorry, that was the excitement when I found the type :D

Comment: @WaqasArshi Your syntax still working, choose the Tigger one to get the same syntax. I just expose in my response another way to declare a class in more conventional way.

Comment: yes i got it. actually i am not a programmer, i am learning, that's why its hard to understand things sometimes. by the way thanQ very much for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
toggleStatus: function(count) {
  var task = this.tasks[count];
    this.tasks[count].status = !task.status;
    this.showTasks();
}
```

Comment: This would be  'this.tasks[count].status = !task.status;'

Comment: @madhur, Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `task`, then changing its status here:

```
toggleStatus: function(count) {
    var task = this.tasks[count];
    task.status = !task.status;
    this.showTasks();
}
```

What you need to do is change the status of the stored `task` in `this.tasks` like so:

```
toggleStatus: function(count) {
    this.tasks[count].status = !this.tasks[count].status;
    this.showTasks();
}
```

**Edit:**

As found by Patrick Ferreira. You also need to change `showTasks` from:

```
if (this.tasks.status === true) {
```

To:

```
if (this.tasks[i].status === true) {
```

Comment: In your solution, `task` is undefined.

Comment: thanQ for your consideration but its not working. when i do (todoList.toggleStatus) it should print that task with (X) as mentioned in showTask function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I would suggest you change `count` to `index`

```
toggleStatus: function(index) {
    this.tasks[index].status = !this.tasks[index].status;
    this.showTasks();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no pass by reference in javascript, so when you are doing this

```
var task = this.tasks[count];
```

It is just making another copy of this.tasks[count] and you are updating this copy, the real value is not getting updated. So this is the problem. The solution is

```
this.tasks[count].status = !this.tasks[count].status;
```

Hope it helps