# About Object methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a class method but I don't see what I am doing wrong here. Here is my code

```
var Invoice = function(title) {
this.title = title;

this.addItem = function addItem(item_name) {
  console.log("Hello, you added " + item_name);
};

invoice = new Invoice("Video games")
invoice.addItem('Xbox 360');
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError at line undefined: invoice.addItem is not a function
```

Comment: `function addItem` should be `function `

Comment: @Mahi: That doesn't actually matter. It's valid to give a function expression a name.

Comment: Jamie: You posted an invalid code snippet because you're missing a `}` somewhere, so it won't run at all. If the closing `}` is *before* the `this.addItem = function...`, then that's your issue.

Comment: It is working. Could you copy & paste the code in console and run(after closing bracket in the function )?

Comment: Try Invoice.prototype.addItem = function(item_name){here your code} and add missed }.

Comment: What do you get if you run `console.log(invoice)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple typo, which goes to show why proper indentation is ESSENTIAL:

```
var Invoice = function(title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.addItem = function addItem(item_name) {
         console.log("Hello, you added " + item_name);
    };
};  //you were not closing your constructor
```

You could, and probably should use `prototype`.

```
var Invoice = function(title) {
    this.title = title;
};
Invoice.prototype.addItem = function(item_name){
     console.log("Hello, you added " + item_name);
};
```

For a detailed explanation of the difference, see [JS - why use prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/js-why-use-prototype)

or in ES6, with a class :

```
class Invoice {
     constructor(title){
         this.title = title;
     }
     addItem(item_name) {
          console.log("Hello, you added " + item_name);
     }
}
```

And in case your invoice is a node module, and your question is made of concatenated code, don't forget to add :

```
module.exports = Invoice;
```

So you can require it anywhere.

In all those cases, invocation is done in the same way :

```
let invoice = new Invoice("Video games") //or var if ES5
invoice.addItem('Xbox 360');
```

Comment: The typo is most likely just in the question, otherwise it would be a SyntaxError instead of a TypeError.

Comment: `TypeError at line undefined:` seems suspicious

Comment: Yes, I wonder if that's output from running in a console. In any case, that placement of `}` does fix it, though I'd imagine the OP would want the function on the `Invoice.prototype`.

Comment: :p been there, done that

Comment: So, using ES6. How do I make it return `[Invoice "Video games"]` when the new instance is created?

Comment: @JaimeRios see edit