# Why does I need .prototype in superClass.prototype when extends it?

Tags: javascript, class, object, inheritance, prototype

Why does I need use `.prototype` in `Shape.prototype` when extends it?

```
// Shape — superClass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  }

Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Figure has rode out somewhere.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); 
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);//<<<=HERE
```

I mean this 'Shape.prototype'.
Why does I need use prototype instead of just Shape? As I know .prototype contains inherited properties and methods of a class. My Shape class is basic and has no inherited properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the purpose of prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433459/what-s-the-purpose-of-prototype)

Comment: *My Shape class is basic and has no inherited properties.* Of course it does - it inherits from `Object`. Now, if you want your `Rectangle` to inherit the `x` and `y` properties of `Shape`, then `Rectangle.prototype` needs to be set to a new instance of `Shape`. Also, don't confuse `Class` with `prototype`. With your code, there are no classes at all, so it's best to leave that word out of the discussion.

Comment: The issue isn't whether `Shape` inherits anything. All the objects you create with `new Shape` inherit from `Shape`.

Answer (score 0):

Methods are usually added to the underlying prototype of an object so that they don't have to be stored in each instance that gets made later. That's the case in this example, the `move()` function is being stored in `Shape.prototype`.

**If you don't use `Shape.prototype` with `Object.create()`, you won't get methods attached to that object inherited to `Rectangle`.**

Technically, you could use just `Object.create(Shape)`, but only in situations where Shape only has instance properties attached directly to it and, even in that case, it wouldn't be a very scalable solution, because if you ever decided to go back and add methods to `Shape.prototype` in the future, none of your sub-types would inherit it.

```js
// Shape — superClass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// Shape.prototype is a unique and specific instance of Object
// This particular instance is what Shape inherits from and is
// the reason why Shape will get a .toString() and a .valueOf()
// method.
console.log(Shape.prototype);

// This method is added to Shape.prototype. If you don't inherit
// from this, you won't inherit this method!!
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Figure has rode out somewhere.');
};

function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); 
}

// If we don't inherit from Shape.prototype, we won't get
// any of the methods attached to it!
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape); 

var r = new Rectangle();

console.log(r.x, r.y);  // Works just fine for instance properties attached direclty to Shape
r.move(10,20);          // Fails because Shape.prototype wasn't used for inheritance!
```