# Why isn't the object __proto__ the constructor function itself?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

I have been reading about prototype (both the `prototype` property that only functions have, as well as `__proto__` that all objects have).

My confusion is about why we need `prototype` property in the first place.

Take below code snippet:

```
function Dog(breed) {
  this.breed = breed;
}

let dog1 = new Dog('chow');
```

The way I understand, functions are also objects in JS. Meaning Dog function is actually an object. A "function object".

So why isn't `__proto__` of dog1, simply the Dog "function object"? Why is it necessary to have another object, "Dog.prototype", as an intermediary?

Instead of:

```
dog1 -> Dog -> global Object
```

We are doing:

```
dog1 -> Dog.prototype -> global Object
                  ↘ 
                   Dog -> global Function Object
```

Related question I found in meantime: [Why is there a need for prototype objects (in functions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181599/why-is-there-a-need-for-prototype-objects-in-functions)

Comment: As a guess, I'd say it's because of the `this` binding. That `this` doesn't mean what you think it means, especially if you come from a more sane OOP language like C++ or C#.

Answer (score 1):

Update: So I was looking into inheritance myself and came across this article you may find interesting - https://www.educba.com/inheritance-in-javascript/. In particular these paragraphs:

> In JavaScript, when creating an object, it creates a link instead of copying behaviors or properties that usually happen in Object-oriented programming languages. In Java, the parent-child class is a separate entity where the properties/behaviors of the parent class are copied into the child class.

> A similar kind of linkage gets created in the case of inheritance of class as well. This pattern is called Behavior Delegation Pattern, commonly referred to as prototypal inheritance in JavaScript. Since a copy is created in Java, all arrows are drawn downwards (properties and behaviors flowing down), whereas, in JavaScript, the flow is upwards.

I think this answers your question, but either way it's an interesting read.

Original Answer:

There's an excerpt in this article I found that you may find interesting:

> There is something misleading in JavaScript regarding prototypes. The prototype of an object is not the same thing as the prototype property of the object. The former is used when looking up non-existent properties in the prototype chain. The latter is used for objects created using new, it will be the prototype of the newly created object. Understanding this difference allows you to fully understand the prototype property in JavaScript. The value holding the prototype of an object is sometimes called the internal prototype link. It's also been historically called **proto**, a name that has some controversy. To be politically correct, it can be called the value that's returned from Object.getPrototypeOf(...).

source: https://bytearcher.com/articles/understanding-prototype-property-in-javascript/

The MDN docs state that proto is also deprecated, so may be worth reading their article too:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: I feel like this explains the “what”. But I don’t really see the “why” part.

Comment: came across some info you might find useful, lmk :)

Comment: In meantime I found a different stackoverflow question that is exactly the same as mine, but formulated and phrased in a lot better way. I will read through to see if there are any valid answers. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181599/why-is-there-a-need-for-prototype-objects-in-functions

Comment: One potential answer by @Bergi: __“You mean why not make the constructor and the prototype object into the same entity? Because the constructor function is a function inheriting methods from Function, and your instances should not transitively inherit those. It does indeed make sense to keep two distinct prototype chains for "static" class methods and instance methods”__ i guess for a 100% indepth answer that i am looking for, i would need to go to the person who made the language design.